# How to prevent an app from removing symbolic linked files (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, symbolic-link

I have a folder `z:\data` on a network drive..

I have a local folder `c:\work` where the following symbolic link exists (created using `mklink`)

```
c:\work\letter.tex => z:\data\letter.tex
```

When I open and edit/save the file `c:\work\letter.tex` in Notepad++, Notepad, etc. It works fine. When I open it in one particular app (Texniccenter) and edit/save in it, the symbolic link gets destroyed and a new unlinked file gets created which is not what I want. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Does Texnicenter create backup file? If yes, try disabling it and see if it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok for others who have this problem. I managed to solve it as follows.
Open properties and go to "Security" option.

1. Take ownership of the file (symbolic link). You may have to take ownership of the parent folder and propagate the changes to children.
2. Add a user "Everyone" with deny permission to "modify"

Thats it! 
Now Texniccentre won't be able to write to the file.